# How to test Completable error in RxJava 3?

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm writing Unit Tests for Completable functions.

In RxJava 2 we have `blockingGet()` as [documented](https://javadoc.io/static/io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxjava/2.2.7/io/reactivex/Completable.html#blockingGet--):

```
Throwable t = myCompletable.blockingGet();
assertTrue(t instanceof MyException);
```

However, in [RxJava 3 documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.reactivex.rxjava3/rxjava/latest/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Completable.html) I don't see `blockingGet()` anymore.

How can I achieve above tests in RxJava 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, it turns out that testing of RxJava is now suggested using `TestObserver` class?

```
TestObserver testObserver = new TestObserver();
myCompletable.blockingSubscribe(testObserver);
testObserver.assertError(MyException.class);
```

Comment: Testing via `TestObserver`/`TestSubscriber` has been preferred ever since 2.0.0. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#testing

Comment: @akarnokd thank you for mentioning it. Is it the reason that `blockingGet()` got removed?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-3.0#completableblockingget